# How to execute PL/SQL code from file and pass blob as parameter

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, blob

I have PL/SQL code such as

```
   begin
      update table set value_blob = empty_blob()
      where expr_id = 2
      returning value_blob into :fileData;
      update table set value_text = 'test'
      where expr_id = 2;
    end;
```

that stored in file. I am trying to execute this procedure and pass another file as **:fileData** parameter:

```
public void handle(String connectionString, String procedure, byte[] dataFile) throws Exception {

    OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
    ods.setURL(connectionString);

    try(Connection conn = ods.getConnection();
        CallableStatement statement = conn.prepareCall(procedure);
        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(dataFile)) {

        statement.setBinaryStream("fileData", inputStream, dataFile.length);
        statement.executeUpdate();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

After executing i have *'test'* value in **value_txt** column, but no data in **value_blob** column. Previous data in this column was changed to empty blob. I tried both named and numbered parameters and i am sure that dataFile byte array is not empty.

Comment: I don't believe that it can work this way, your procedure should be stored in your db, then you will be able to call it using CallableStatement https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6009.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i am correctly understand your question, you are expecting that statement

```
  update table set value_blob = empty_blob()
  where expr_id = 2
  returning value_blob into :fileData;
```

will return non-empty value. But `returning` clause return updated value i.e. result of `empty_blob()`
That's why you see no data in `value_blob` column.

If you want update value_blob column try to use

```
update table set value_blob = (RAWTOHEX(UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw('some data'))) 
      where expr_id = 2
      returning value_blob into :fileData;
```